# How to display default setup of variation attributes in Woocommerce additional info product tab?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress website build with Woocommcerce. I have a variable product with four attributes. I setup a default variation in this product and it displays on product page. Now I want to display only the default setup attributes terms in "additional_info" tab. For example: I have color attribute with four terms (red, black, white, green). I set the default to red. And I want to display in additional info tabs only this "red" term of attribute color.

I used this code to do a similar thing with the price:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $selectedPrice = '';
    $dump = '';

    foreach ( $available_variations as $variation )
    {
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($variation['attributes'], true) . '</pre>';

        $isDefVariation=false;
        foreach($product->get_default_attributes() as $key=>$val){
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($key, true) . '</pre>';
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$key]==$val){
                $isDefVariation=true;
            }   
        }
        if($isDefVariation){
            $price = $variation['display_price'];         
        }
    }
    $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);

//  $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($available_variations, true) . '</pre>';

    return $selectedPrice . $dump;
}
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This code paste in your active theme functions.php file. and replace your attribute name with **'pa_color'** attribute.
Hide attribute which one you customised.

```
<?php function action_woocommerce_product_additional_information( $wc_display_product_attributes ) { 
    $defult_arr_name = $wc_display_product_attributes->get_default_attributes();
    ?>
    <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes">
        <tbody>
            <?php if($defult_arr_name['pa_color']) { ?>
            <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_display_price">
                <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">Color</th>
                <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><p><?php echo $defult_arr_name['pa_color']; ?></p></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'action_woocommerce_product_additional_information', 10, 2 );
```